# PineScript strategy alerts get triggered during premarket hours in 1D timeframe. How to fix it?

Tags: pine-script

I created a strategy that executes when the market opens.
My exchange's live trading window starts at `09:15`.

But the pine script generates the alert exactly at `09:07`.

I am trying to achieve automated trading through webhooks, but alerts generated during pre market hours do not get executed.

I am using the **1 Day interval** chart & using the following code:

```
backtestStartDate = input.time(timestamp("07 Nov 2023"))
tradingHours = na(time(timeframe.period, "0915-1530")) ? false : true
iAmInATrade = strategy.position_size != 0
inTradeWindow = time >= backtestStartDate and tradingHours 

smoothK = 3
smoothD = 3

k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, length), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
if (not na(k) and not na(d) and inTradeWindow and not iAmInATrade)
    if (k>d)
        buyQuantity = math.floor(AmtToInvest/close)
        strategy.entry("StochLE", strategy.long, qty = buyQuantity)
```

How can I resolve this issue? I think I can create a workaround on minutes or hourly interval chart, but I strongly prefer it to work on the 1D chart.

Btw, is it possible that it works with `session.ismarket` instead of `tradingHours`?

Please guide.

Comment: Where is the code that triggers your alert?

Comment: @vitruvius updated the question with the trigger code

Comment: I still don't see any alert code. Do you mean `strategy.entry()`?

Comment: Which exchange do you use?